# What in the POSIX standard prevents alias substitution when there is backslash in the command or the command is quoted?

Tags: shell, posix, alias

I have defined an alias like this.

```
[user@centos ~]$ alias echo='echo aliased echo says: '
[user@centos ~]$ echo hi
aliased echo says: hi
```

Why does alias substitution not take place when there is a backslash or part of the command is quoted as shown below? Can you explain it by citing the relevant sections from POSIX standard at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/.

```
[user@centos ~]$ \echo hi
hi
[user@centos ~]$ ec\ho hi
hi
[user@centos ~]$ "echo" hi
hi
[user@centos ~]$ ec"ho" hi
hi
[user@centos ~]$ command echo hi
hi
[user@centos ~]$ command -v echo
alias echo='echo aliased echo says: '
```

Quoting the relevant section from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html

> ***2.3.1 Alias Substitution***
>
> After a token has been delimited, but before applying the grammatical
>   rules in Shell Grammar, a resulting word that is identified to be the
>   command name word of a simple command shall be examined to determine
>   whether it is an unquoted, valid alias name. However, reserved words
>   in correct grammatical context shall not be candidates for alias
>   substitution. A valid alias name (see XBD Alias Name) shall be one
>   that has been defined by the alias utility and not subsequently
>   undefined using unalias. Implementations also may provide predefined
>   valid aliases that are in effect when the shell is invoked. To prevent
>   infinite loops in recursive aliasing, if the shell is not currently
>   processing an alias of the same name, the word shall be replaced by
>   the value of the alias; otherwise, it shall not be replaced.
>
> If the value of the alias replacing the word ends in a <blank>,
>   the shell shall check the next command word for alias substitution;
>   this process shall continue until a word is found that is not a valid
>   alias or an alias value does not end in a <blank>.
>
> When used as specified by this volume of POSIX.1-2008, alias
>   definitions shall not be inherited by separate invocations of the
>   shell or by the utility execution environments invoked by the shell;
>   see Shell Execution Environment.

Is there anything in the above section that causes this?

Comment: **Is there anything in the above section that causes this?** Sorry, but it's like: I can't read, please find it for me.

Comment: @Mike That section, 'Section 2.3.1 Alias Substitution', alone does not explain how backslash prevents alias substitution. Hence, this question. FYI such a question is allowed on StackOverflow. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development). This is a practial, answerable question about shell scripting. See the answered marked correct. My question can be answered only after referring to 'Section 2.2 Quoting' that explains that backslash is one of 3 quoting mechanisms. Such a useful answer serves the purpose of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is something: the word **unquoted** in "... determine whether it is an unquoted, valid alias name." This sentence supresses alias substitution when any part of a command word is quoted.

There are *three* quoting mechanisms in the shell: backslash, single and double quotes.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This perfectly answers my question. I searched for "quoting mechanisms" in the document and found the answer in ***Section 2.2 Quoting*** that mentions, "The various quoting mechanisms are the escape character, single-quotes, and double-quotes. The here-document represents another form of quoting; see [Here-Document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07_04)."